# trouble turning symbolized functions into RPN form

Tags: c++

I'm trying to convert symbolized functions ( functions represented with a symbol, like: √ and Σ ) into RPN form, but it doesn't work because an expression like "√√100" would convert into √100√, how do I make it convert √√100 -> 100√√ ? of course I could do it like √(√(100)) but that gets messy fast, so I want to avoid adding brackets if possible.

my current rpn converter:

```
std::wstring revpol(std::wstring parsedf, std::wstring mtok)
{
    std::wstring tparsed;
std::wistringstream mplit(parsedf);
while(mplit >> mtok)
{
        mspec = false;
if(rxm(mtok,pnum))
{
tparsed += mtok + L" ";
}

else{
            if(Pval[mtok] == 0)
    {
        mspec = true;
    }
        if(mspec){
if(mtok == L"(")
       {
preop.push({mtok,Pval[mtok]});
        mspec = false;
       }
 else if(mtok == L")") {
    while(preop.top().first != L"(")
    {
        tparsed += preop.top().first + L" ";
       preop.pop();
    }
    if(preop.top().first == L"(")
    {
             preop.pop();
    }
             mspec = false;

 }
else if(mtok == L",")
{
    tparsed += mtok + L" ";
                 mspec = false;

}
else{
if(mtok.back() == '$'){
// to be changed
    Tmtok = mtok;
  mtok.pop_back();
Pval.insert({mtok,3});
mtok = Tmtok;
mspec = false;
std::cout<<preop.size()<<std::endl;
       while(!preop.empty() && preop.top().second >= 3 && mtok != L"^")
       {
           tparsed += preop.top().first + L" ";
           preop.pop();
       }
   preop.push({mtok,3});
}
else{

    tparsed += mtok + L" ";
mspec = false;
}

}
```

Comment: Please provide minimum reproducible example of what you have implemented

Comment: @TheDreamsWind is that a minimum reproducible example?